# Storing single mysql value into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to grab a single value from a table in my database. The code is below. However, when I run it, the console.log says it's NaN and on inspection, there is no value in the code. Is there anything specific I've done wrong or something I can improve?

```js
<script>
        var pos_one_lat = parseFloat(
            <?php 
                $db = mysqli_connect('ip', 'user', 'pass (;)', 'table'); 
                $result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `latitude` FROM geodesics WHERE `stamp`=1');
                $lat = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
                echo "'$lat'";
                mysqli_close($db); 
            ?>);
        console.log(pos_one_lat);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$lat` you get an object

so for accessing value you have to do like this

```
echo $lat->latitude;
```

Comment: This still produces NaN (output is ' '). The database value for latitude when stamp = 1 is -27.5551818.

Comment: first you print $lat like this...  print_r($lat); and post your answer

Comment: so rather than using echo use print_r($lat)? This prints 1 not -27. Although we are getting close.

Comment: you can directly print using print_r($lat);

Comment: This hasn’t worked either unfortunately. I don’t understand why

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `parseFloat`. Just echo the variable in PHP and use that as the value of the Javascript variable. The syntax of floating point numbers is the same in PHP and Javascript.

And to access a specific column from the result, you need to use `$lat->latitude`.

```
<script>
    var pos_one_lat = 
        <?php 
            $db = mysqli_connect('ip', 'user', 'pass (;)', 'table'); 
            $result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `latitude` FROM geodesics WHERE `stamp`=1');
            $lat = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
            echo $lat->latitude;
            mysqli_close($db); 
        ?>;
    console.log(pos_one_lat);
</script>
```

Comment: When I use the variable with the google map api it has to be a float

Comment: Why do you think it won't be a float when you do this? There are no quotes around the value.

Comment: Precaution I’d say. I have almost no experience with php and MySQL so I’m just making sure I do everything right. Although none of these methods have worked so far unfortunately

Comment: What do you see when you use `View Source`?

Comment: <script>
        var pos_one_lat = parseFloat(
            </script>

Comment: There's no `parseFloat`in my answer.